# InputStream from getResourceAsStream results in NULL

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, nullpointerexception, inputstream

```
        InputStream input = Faculty.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Resources\\Names.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null && !strLine.equals("")) {
            keywords.add(strLine);
        }
```

The code above works in NetBeans. But when I packed the code into an executable Jar and ran it from command line, it gave me a NullPointerException because of the non-initialized `input`. So I suspect the Jar was not able to read the resource file packaged in it. The folder `Resources` is directly under source folder of my project. Can anyone give some hint what to try?

Comment: what have you tried?  Also you are not using that input stream anywhere, looks like you have an fstream elsewhere

Comment: what is the full qualified path to Names.txt file ?

Comment: @Farlan Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: @user717630 It is under the source folder of my project.

Comment: Is the path to Resources in your classpath? eg: ./somepath/ in your classpath if Resources is under ./somepath/Resources/?

Comment: I feel I must ask the obvious first: have you extracted the jar to ensure your resource has been packaged?

Comment: @cklab Everything is there as I expected.

Comment: @TerryLi In that case, I suggest attempting to use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` as your loader and not the `Faculty` ClassLoader.

Comment: @Farlan The absolute path is `MyProject/src/Resources`. I just checked the manifest file of my Jar and it included all of my lib paths.

Comment: @cklab That was a great suggestion as I work in multi-threaded environment. I just tried it without luck.

Comment: @cklab By the way, the code is in an initializer block of a class that extends `Thread'.

Comment: Try forward slash instead of backslash (Resources/Names.txt) and also be aware name might be case sensitive if reading from JAR or case sensitive filesystem.

Comment: @prunge Tried both of them. Didn't work either.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this:

```
getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Names.txt");
```

if you don't add the prefix '/', it means that your path is based on your class path, not the root path